# Translate sentence and grammar question

Tags: traducción, gramática

I'm reading this paper [1] and I can't translate a sentence to Spanish (well, I'm not pretty sure). The sentence is: **"the scheme is correct if the verification algorithm accepts when interacting with the valid prover"**.
I've tried this translate "El esquema es correcto, si el algoritmo de verificación es aceptado cuando interactúa con el proveedor"

P.D The author is Asian and therefore I'm not secure if the sentence is correctly English written. So if the grammar it's ok, can someone explain where to read about this conjugation?.

[1] Enabling Public Auditability and Data Dynamics for Storage Security in Cloud Computing, Wang et. al., 2010. DOI: 10.1109/TPDS.2010.183

Comment: Creo que la duda surge principalmente de la redacción original en inglés. Lo que más me llama la atención es el uso de "accept" como verbo intransitivo. Según Merriam-Webster (y Jane Austen), es correcto, pero para mí ofusca el significado. Otro problema es que el autor sustituyó "server"  (que aparecía en la frase anterior) por "prover" sin razón alguna. El significado previsto es "si el algoritmo acepta el servidor válido".  Tal vez "si el algoritmo de verificación da la aceptación cuando interactúa con el demostrador."

Comment: I think you mean "provider" in place of "prover" in the English, and can you verify the spelling on that second word?  Is it "scheme" or "schema"?

Comment: That sentence is not idiomatic in English.  We wouldn't say: "if the algorithm accepts".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the English is not right and this is not really a translation site.

Answer (score 2):

As a Computer Science graduate educated in Spain, I'd tell you that this use of "accepts" is theoretical Computer Science jargon, meaning that a (not explicitly mentioned as far I've read) Turing machine accepts whatever word the prover happens to give it.

In the Turing machine formalism, a Turing machine can **accept** a word (or stop in an **accepting state**, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)), reject it or never stop. Whether a machine accepts a set of words or not is used to represent things that we might actually want to compute in a mathematical framework that is well studied.

So, I'd translate this sentence as "la estrategia es correcta si el algoritmo de verificación acepta [también: termina en estado de aceptación] al interactuar con el demostrador válido".

Although this use of "acepta" is **not** idiomatic Spanish, I believe that is considered idiomatic within the CS jargon among Spanish speakers, as is the case for many mistranslated words from the original English jargon.

Similarly, I've chosen to translate "scheme" as "estrategia", but I wouldn't be surprised if "esquema" is used among CS practitioners who are Spanish speakers. Let me also suggest "sistema", as is used, for instance, in "criptosistema", a word which I've seen used too by CS professors.

Comment: Yes, accept [something], not just accepts.

Answer (score 1):

> "the scheme is correct if the verification algorithm accepts when
> interacting with the valid prover"

I might consider the following options--but these are just ideas.  Please use your own judgment.

Direct/literal:

- "El esquema es correcto si el algoritmo de verificación acepta cuando se interactúa con el proveedor válido."

A bit more interpretive would be:

- "El esquema es correcto si el algoritmo de verificación acepta *al interactuarse* con el proveedor válido."

A bit more interpretive yet, but perhaps more idiomatic in Spanish:

- "El esquema es correcto si el algoritmo de verificación *hace que* acepta cuando se interactúa con el proveedor válido."

NOTE: I have not seen the original article.  I'm assuming that "prover" was a typo intended to be "provider."  If the English word should be "schema," then perhaps "esquemático" might be considered.  To be more certain, the context of the sentence, for example, seeing the whole paragraph, would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you use "interactuar**se**"? As far as I know, [interactuar](https://dle.rae.es/interactuar) is not a pronominal verb.

Comment: @wimi Tienes razón.  Perhaps interactuar is better.  My thinking may have been influenced by "relacionarse."  The challenge was not having a direct object for "accept," and trying to connect the action back to the algorithm.